# What does ssl.client.auth specify?

Tags: apache-kafka

Does setting ssl.client.auth=required mean that the client's certificate has to be added to the kafka truststore?

Regards,
Yash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `ssl.client.auth=required` means that clients will need to pass SSL/TLS client authentication which is based on the truststore.

The truststore should contain certificates of trusted certification authorities. So if your clients use signed certificates, you should put the certificate of this certification authority into the truststore. That would allow all clients who have a certificate signed with this CA to authenticate.

If you use self-signed certificates or if you want only selected signed certificates to authenticate, you can put directly their certificates into the truststore. But they will be treated as trusted CAs - so if the client uses its client certificate as a CA and sign more certificates, these will be also able to authenticate. So this is not completely secure.

Comment: I tried adding only the Issuer of the client cert to the trust store. The communication failed. Only when I also added the client certificate to the the trust store, the communication went through.

Comment: If you use Java client, you can use system property `javax.net.debug=ssl` ... that will give you a lot of debug messages which can help to debug any issues. The things to look for are:
a) Does the broker advertise the CA certificate to the client and b) Does the client send the certificate.

Comment: The phrase "clients need to pass SSL/TLS client authentication" is confusing.  If I am using a SCRAM-512 username/password, this is authentication.  I am using the client.  From this perspective I am using client authentication.  But I don't believe this qualifies as TLS authentication.  I think the `ssl.client.auth` setting is for Mutual TLS (mTLS) requirements.  It specifies the rule - if the client needs to send an x509 cert to the broker.

Comment: Yeah ... TLS client authentication (or SSL client authentication) is basically the same as mTLS. SCRAM-SHA authentication is something else and is not configured by `ssl.client.auth`.